Process to re-ignite a thread on quant finance in stack exchange
I posted a question a while ago on quant stackexchange but seems like not a lot of people have viewed it and it hasn't received any response. What are some ways I can re-ignite that thread and bring it under focus for viewers? 
Also, I'm just curious - why doesn't stack exchange have a forum to ask career related questions in quant finance?  That would be so useful. Quantnet and WSO exist but stackexchange is the best :) 

These are exceptional times and that might be the reason your question didn't get the attention that it otherwise would have gotten.
The best way to focus attention on your question is giving a bounty. 
To your other question: StackOverflow Jobs does exist. We don't allow career questions for a few reasons:

They are likely to be specific to you
Another stack exists for workplace related questions
They don't fit well in a Q&A format
It tends to attract not great questions

